# Basic gcp cloudsql user id/password question

Tags: authentication, gcloud

I've created postgres database in a gcp cloud instance. I then created an id, via terraform, named pgsox-user, that showed up in IAM.  I then created that same id in the sql database section. I set the password to 'sandbox' and when I run my test script via curl from my laptop it connects and works fine.

When I use the gcp portal, ie cloudshell, and connect to the same database I see that it connects as user postgres by default:

```
    gcloud sql connect rcw-test-pg --user=postgres --quiet
```

due to other issues I've had (not important here) I decided to try to connect via pgsox-user:

```
   gcloud sql connect rcw-test-pg --user=pgsox-user --quiet
```

But, this doesn't accept my password, sandbox.

Why I can connect via my script, which uses pgsox-user/sandbox but the same combination fails from the cloudshell?

Are these somehow treated differently? What am I missing per understanding of logins/passwords to these cloudsql databases?